# Three(little) questions about getOrCreateWithCypher()

Tags: neo4j

i have this two pieces of code

```
try ( Transaction tx = graphdb.beginTx() )
{
    graphdb.schema()
            .constraintFor( DynamicLabel.label( "User" ) )
            .assertPropertyIsUnique( "name" )
            .create();
    tx.success();
}

return new ExecutionEngine( graphdb() );
```

AND

```
Node result = null;
ResourceIterator<Node> resultIterator = null;
try ( Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx() )
{
    String queryString = "MERGE (n:User {name: {name}}) RETURN n";
    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    parameters.put( "name", username );
    resultIterator = engine.execute( queryString, parameters ).columnAs( "n" );
    result = resultIterator.next();
    tx.success();
    return result;
}
```

It is likely that these two separate methods? if so:
Is every time I make a new object I have read the **two** methods?

And lastly:

```
return new ExecutionEngine (graphDb ());
```

I get an error suggested I build the method graphDb () Is there a need for this?

Comment: I don't understand your questions, but assuming `graphDb` is your `GraphDatabaseService` object you are calling it as if it were a method when you should pass the reference. Do `new ExecutionEngine(graphDb);`, without the parentheses.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Regarding the first question, my intention is whether any creation of new (Unique) Nod  I have to call 2 methods? 

And is it possible to call like this: 

`Node classNode = getOrCreateWithCypher (classString, db, createExecutionEngineAndConstraint (db)); `

I could not figure out which method is called before the other.

Answer (score 1):

As jjaderberg notes, you need to remove the parenthesises from new ExecutionEngine, like this:

```
return new ExecutionEngine(graphDb);
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your other question.

You only have to create the constraint once in the lifetime of your db.

So you could even do it on the command line or in the browser or in a migration script.

Usually you create the `GraphDatabaseService` and `ExecutionEngine` only once and pass them around. Just make sure to `shutdown()` the graph database at the end of your program or via a ShutdownHook.

You can probably simplify the code a bit by using some helper methods:

```
private final static String MERGE_USER = "MERGE (n:User {name: {name}}) RETURN n";

try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
    Node result =  single(engine.execute( MERGE_USER, map("name",username )).columnAs( "n" ));
    tx.success();
    return result;
}
```

And as Cypher handles its own transaction, you don't need the outer tx:

```
    Node result =  single(engine.execute( MERGE_USER, map("name",username )).columnAs( "n"
```